# Why there is no back links displayed from SN sites (twitter, Facebook, gplus) in Google Webmaster?

Tags: google, google-search-console, backlinks, social-media

We have built backlinks from Social networking websites such as gplus, Facebook and LinkedIn for many websites.

For some websites, In web master, We see very less number of links and for some websites, we see no links.

Why is it so ?
Google does not count the links from Social networking websites ?

Answer (score 1):

Google search console shows the linking domains and sorts them by the count of linking pages.
Maybe total number of your Twitter or Facebook posts are not that many so they are not listed among top-1000 linking websites that GSC reports.

For a website that I'm checking now, even Instagram is listed with only 1 linking page (Profile bio link).

Answer (score 1):

Those sites typically block Google from crawling much of their content. Either because the content is private fore each user, or because they don't want Google stealing their information.

If Google is blocked, it won't see the links.

Even if it does, the page or link will probably be marked as nofollow and/or go via an intermediary domain, which may also cause the link not to be reported.

Comment: Neither Facebook nor Twitter block Google-bot from crawling important pages (Like single-post page ).

Comment: You're right, Twitter is very open at the moment. In fact you will see Google showing tweets in their search results. Not so much love between Facebook and Google.